# Check if user assigned to particular slot

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on people staffing application. We have a feature where we transfer employees to teams. I want to add validation to check if the user already booked for that particular period. For example, in below screenshot user **mate** slot is overlapping. He can't be assigned to two teams within the same time period.

[image]

This question is more about data structure. The code I wrote it seems working but still, I am not confident about it I believed it could have done in a better way. Like without running two loops?.

It is okay if we need to modify the data structure to get better performance.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pj2kmz1kox

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedItem: {}
  };
  updateDate = (index, field, { target: { value } }) => {
    const { selectedItem } = this.state;
    const newSelectedItem = { ...selectedItem };
    newSelectedItem[index] = newSelectedItem[index] || {
      id: new Date().getTime()
    };
    newSelectedItem[index][field] = new Date(value);
    this.setState({
      selectedItem: newSelectedItem
    });
    this.valiateAvailibility();
  };

  handleDropdown = (index, { target: { value } }) => {
    const { selectedItem } = this.state;
    const newSelectedItem = { ...selectedItem };
    newSelectedItem[index] = newSelectedItem[index] || {
      id: new Date().getTime()
    };
    newSelectedItem[index]["userId"] = value;
    this.setState({
      selectedItem: newSelectedItem
    });
    this.valiateAvailibility();
  };

  valiateAvailibility = () => {
    const { selectedItem } = this.state;
    const error = {};
    for (let i in selectedItem) {
      const userId = selectedItem[i].userId;
      const id = selectedItem[i].id;
      const from = selectedItem[i].from;
      const to = selectedItem[i].to;
      for (let z in selectedItem) {
        const fromB = selectedItem[z].from;
        const toB = selectedItem[z].to;
        if (userId == selectedItem[z].userId && id !== selectedItem[z].id) {
          if (from <= toB && to >= fromB) {
            error[z] = "error";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    console.log("error", error);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.selectedItem);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {[1, 2, 3].map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <select onChange={e => this.handleDropdown(index, e)}>
                <option>Select User</option>
                <option value="12">Mate</option>
                <option value="23">Bill</option>
              </select>
              <input
                type="date"
                onChange={e => this.updateDate(index, "from", e)}
              />
              <input
                type="date"
                onChange={e => this.updateDate(index, "to", e)}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you do some own research? And if there is a need to show code, do it without using links. Without even trying to check out the link i recommend searching for keywords like *interval-trees* or maybe even more interesting in regards to what you are doing: *constraint-programming + disjunctive scheduling* (which is more than just checking for overlappings)

Answer (score 1):

This demo has a `class` with a few methods that use ES6 Map to store Date ranges. Each instentation represents an employee's schedule. OP did not mention what to do with overlapping dates so here is the Date range validation rules:

- Dates are converted into milliseconds for comparison (`.getTime()`)
- If a start date is greater than another start date and is less than its end date, then the earliest start date is used and then the new end date will be the greater of the two end dates.
- If input start date is greater than input end date, they are swapped.
- Each range is stored by an index.

BTW the Dates are accurate but the format varies, I'll leave that up to the OP.

```js
class schedule {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.index = 0;
    this.map = new Map;
  }
  addSlot([startString, endString]) {
    this.index = this.map.size;
    let startDate = new Date(startString);
    let endDate = new Date(endString);
    let startTime = startDate.getTime();
    let endTime = endDate.getTime()
    if (startTime > endTime) {
      let temp = endDate;
      endDate = startDate;
      startDate = temp;
    }
    if (this.map.size > 0) {
      for (let [key, value] of this.map) {
        let start = value[0].getTime();
        let end = value[1].getTime();
        let newStart = startTime > start && startTime < end ? value[0] : start > startTime && start < endTime ? startDate : false;
        let newEnd;
        if (newStart) {
          newEnd = end > endTime ? value[1] : endDate;
          this.map.set(key, [newStart, newEnd]);
        } else {
          this.map.set(this.index, [startDate, endDate]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.map.set(this.index, [startDate, endDate]);
    }
  }

  hasSlot(index) {
    return this.map.has(index);
  }

  getSlot(index) {
    return this.map.get(index);
  }

  viewSlots() {
    let list = '';
    for (let [key, value] of this.map) {
      list += `
      ${key}: [Start: ${value[0]} - 
          End: ${value[1]}]
      `;
    }
    return list;
  }

  removeSlot(index) {
    if (this.map.has(index)) {
      this.map.delete(index);
    } else {
      return index + 'does not exist';
    }
  }
}

const m = new schedule('Mate');

console.log(m.id);

m.addSlot(['04/19/2019', '04/28/2019']);
console.log(m.hasSlot(0));

m.addSlot(['04/21/2019', '05/12/2019']);
console.log(m.hasSlot(1));
console.log(m.getSlot(0));

m.addSlot(['08/19/2019', '09/12/2019']);
console.log(m.hasSlot(1));
console.log(m.getSlot(1));

console.log(m.viewSlots());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a more efficient data structure you can try to use a binary tree here. Put your non-overlapping intervals into that tree.

Since you’re interested in non-overlapping intervals you have a natural order defined on them: interval A > interval B if A lays to the right of B on the time axis.

You can add intervals one by one checking at the same time that every new interval isn’t overlapping with existing ones. For every new interval it will take O(log n). If an interval is edited then you have to remove the corresponding node and add a new one, keeping the binary tree structure of course.

In practice however you probably have a small number of intervals and it doesn’t make any sense to use a complex data structure. You’re perfectly fine using a simple list of intervals and iterating over it.